# Is it possible to create a completely empty Nether dimension?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible in Bedrock Edition to create an empty Nether dimension? Not just an empty overworld but a world such that when I go through a Nether portal the world is empty?

I am making a skyblock map and this would be awesome, I've got the empty overworld sorted but the Nether is proving tricky.

I know I could use a tool like Amulet to just delete lots of blocks but this doesn't seem very elegant.

I know this question has been asked but note that they were asking for Java Edition.

## Edit

Behaviour packs or .mcfunctions etc. would also be adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out.

Using a behaviour pack and `.mcfunction` files along with the `tick.json` file I can run a command on every tick.

The command I then run is `execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ 127 ~ bedrock 0 fill ~-8 127 ~-8 ~8 0 ~8 air`

This removes the 16 x 128 x 16 area around a player *only when a bedrock block is found at y coordinate 128 at the player's position.

As bedrock is only generated on the ceiling of the Nether and players cannot place bedrock this will only remove newly generated chunks.

It could be expanded to include the 8 other zones around the player to remove a bigger area (N, S, E, W, NE, SE, SW, NW).